# Next js edge runtime problem with reflect metadata

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I am using a package that includes reflect metadata, in my next 13 app. When I run next build I face this error and I have got no work-around.

```
../../eshop-sdk-js/node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js
Dynamic Code Evaluation (e. g. 'eval', 'new Function', 'WebAssembly.compile') not allowed in Edge Runtime
```

I tried to find a alternative library instead of reflect meta data but there is none. I'm seeking a work around to skip this error.

Comment: It looks like reflect is denied specifically because of security concerns.  Here's the docs: https://vercel.com/docs/functions/edge-functions/limitations

Answer (score 0):

I "fixed" it by adding a config that forces the runtime to ignore code evaluation for reflect-metadata files.

Add this config to your middleware config (e.g. middleware.ts):

```js
export const config = {
  unstable_allowDynamic: [
    '/node_modules/reflect-metadata/**',
  ],
};
```

https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/edge#unsupported-apis